# How to add the frame labels to the given plot code?

Tags: plotting, labeling, frame, labeled

Using this code

```
p0 := Plot[ 1, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[1], Thickness[.005]], Axes -> {False, True}];
pn0 := Plot[ 2, {y, 0, 3}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[1], Thickness[.005]], Axes -> {False, True}];

Show[{Show[{p0}, PlotRange -> {-1, 4}, AspectRatio -> 1/4], Show[{pn0}, PlotRange -> {-1, 4}, AspectRatio -> 1/4] /. Line[y_] :> Line[{-1, 1} # & /@ y]}, PlotRange -> {{-3, 10}, {-1, 4}}
, Ticks -> {Transpose[{#, Abs@#} &@Range[-3, 10, 2]], None}, 
 Frame -> True, ImagePadding -> 40, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{0, 1, 2, 3}, None}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

I get this plot but without the labels $\{x,y,z\}$; how can I add these labels to the given code? (I have two different labels for the horizontal axis, the left and right-hand side of zero)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

p0 = Plot[1, {x, 0, 10}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, CapForm["Butt"], Thickness[.005]]];

pn0 = Plot[2, {y, 0, 3}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, CapForm["Butt"], Thickness[.005]]];

Show[p0, pn0 /. Line[y_] :> Line[{-1, 1} # & /@ y],
 Graphics[
  Text[Style[#[[1]], 14], Scaled[#[[2]]]] & /@
   {{"x", {8/13, -0.3}},
    {"y", {1/13, -0.3}}}], 
 PlotRange -> {{-3, 10}, {-1, 4}},
 Axes -> {False, True},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {None, Style["z ", 14, Black]},
 RotateLabel -> False,
 ImagePadding -> {{30, 10}, {35, 10}},
 FrameTicks ->
  {{{0, 1, 2, 3}, None}, {Automatic, None}},
 AspectRatio -> 1/4,
 PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image]